# Luxon - set milliseconds for toISO()

Tags: milliseconds, luxon

I'm using the following to get the end of day for a date coming from a date picker:

```
var date = DateTime.fromISO('2018-05-05').endOf('day');
```

What I want to end up with is

```
"2018-05-05T23:59:59+02:00"
```

however, I cannot get rid of the milliseconds:

```
console.log(date.toISO({suppressMilliseconds: true}));
// => outputs "2018-05-05T23:59:59.999+02:00"
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this besides simply setting the `millisecond` to 0:

```
date.c.millisecond = 0;
console.log(date.toISO({suppressMilliseconds: true}));
// => outputs "2018-05-05T23:59:59+02:00"
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Right, `suppressMilliseconds` only applies if they're 0. (See [here](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js~DateTime.html#instance-method-toISO)).

But there's a much easier way to round down the second:

```
DateTime.fromISO('2018-05-05')
  .endOf('day')
  .startOf('second')
  .toISO({ suppressMilliseconds: true })
```

You should never mutate the Luxon object like in your workaround.

Answer (score 6):

```
const { DateTime } = require("luxon");
let time = DateTime.now().set({milliseconds: 0});
time = time.toISO({suppressMilliseconds: true});
console.log(time);
```

It should help and solve the problem.

Comment: The OP asks about the end of the day, your variation is working with now(). There is an accepted answer and its pretty much fulfilling the task.

Answer (score 0):

The way I did :

```
DateTime.now().toISO().replace(/\.\d{0,3}/, "");
```

Using RegExp to remove the "." and millis
I was having

> 2021-02-22T18:03:29.519Z

With the replace RegExp

> 2021-02-22T18:05:44Z